# Upload File to S3 Dynamic Storage

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm having problems uploading files to a dynamic storage service.

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: env.s3.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: env.s3.sharedSecret,
    httpOptions: {
        agent: proxy(env.auth.proxy),
    },
});

this.s3Client = new AWS.S3({ endpoint: env.s3.accessHost, signatureVersion: 'v2' });
```

This is the configuration. I have to define the proxy settings since I'm behind the Swisscom corp proxy.

```
public upload(image: IFile): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const key = image.originalname;
        const paramsCreateFile = { Bucket: 'test', Key: key, Body: image.buffer };

        this.s3Client.putObject(paramsCreateFile, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

And this is my upload method.
However, when I try to upload nothing happens. After approx. 2 mins I get a timeout, but no error.

I followed the official [documentation](https://github.com/swisscom/dynstrg-howto) during implementation.

Comment: are you running the code on Swisscoms Application Cloud or on your machine?

Comment: on my machine, but will deploy to the App Cloud as soon as it works

Comment: please note that you do not need a proxy when you deploy it on the Appcloud. Do you use the public cloud of Swisscom (developer.swisscom.com) or some private Swisscom cloud?

Comment: i use the internal App Cloud and yes the proxy settings are not set on the cloud

Comment: Can you try using a older version of the AWS SDK? There have been some problems with the V2 signing tn the latest AWS SDK.

Comment: tried 2.7.0 and 2.4.0 - same result

Comment: Please try to replace your current hostname with 'ds11s3' or 'ds41s3'. The current domain you're using might not be resolvable outside the Appcloud.

Comment: host already was ds41s3-scs.swisscom.com.
ds11s3-scs.swisscom.com throws an error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163648/discussion-between-lafunamor-and-timo-jokinen).